# Leaflet.Editable is not working with the latest version of Leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

I am trying to work with [Leaflet.Editable](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable) plugin on [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/index.html), so I add controls on my map and draw different shapes.

Although the examples are working pretty well, I could not run this plugin on the latest version of leaflet, `version 1.1.0`, and it keeps telling me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: L.Polyline._flat is not a function
    at NewClass.initVertexMarkers (Leaflet.Editable.js:1022)
    at NewClass.addHooks (Leaflet.Editable.js:1015)
    at NewClass.enable (leaflet-src.js:5559)
    at NewClass.enableEdit (Leaflet.Editable.js:1736)
    at NewClass.startRectangle (Leaflet.Editable.js:336)
    at NewClass.<anonymous> (MyJSFile:128)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.handler (leaflet-src.js:2225)
```

Why is this happening? Should the community update the plugin accordingly?

> P.S. Editable Examples are working on version 1.0.3

Comment: Leaflet 1.1.0 was released less than 2 weeks ago. The maintainers are working on it, you can check the GIthub issues page for progress, give it some time. I'm voting to close this question because it's not really a programming or code issue.

Comment: Someone with a different problem changed version (to the latest) that fixed the problem. So maybe try some different versions?